# impossible to connect to SOLR with JDBC URL

Tags: url, jdbc, solr, timeout, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to connect to Solr with JDBC, but I always have

> "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper localhost:9983/ within 15000 ms"

(or other port, depends which jdbc URL I test).

Here what I did:

- I installed Solr 7.7.2 ([install doc here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/installing-solr.html)), i.e. download, extract, start (without option : bin/solr start)
- I added a 'test' collection and the examples xml documents, I can [see them at this url](http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=*%3A*)
- then I installed DbVisualizer, added driver and a connection, like [explained here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/solr-jdbc-dbvisualizer.html)
  => the only differences I saw with documentation is that on screencopy with the jar to import, versions are different and there is one more jar in solr archive (commons-math3-3.6.1.jar). Also, the jdbc URL to use is with or without a '/' in the middle ([see here](http://jdbc:solr://localhost:9983?collection=test)), as this : jdbc:solr://localhost:9983?collection=test or jdbc:solr://localhost:9983/?collection=test. Don't know if it is important...
- and I tried both on Ubuntu VM and Windows 10

So, all seems to be good, as in documentation, but when I click on 'connect', always have a timeout. Every website I found info talk about the first jdbc URL in my list below, I tried other possibilities (just in case) but no success...

- jdbc:solr://localhost:9983?collection=test
- jdbc:solr://127.0.0.1:9983?collection=test
- jdbc:solr://localhost:9983/?collection=test
- jdbc:solr://localhost:9983/solr?collection=test
- jdbc:solr://localhost:8983/?collection=test
- jdbc:solr://localhost:8983?collection=test
- jdbc:solr://localhost:8983/solr?collection=test
- jdbc:solr://localhost:2181?collection=test
- jdbc:solr://localhost:2181/?collection=test
- jdbc:solr://localhost:2181/solr?collection=test

If you have an idea, thanks for help!

Comment: Have you started Solr in cloud mode? (i.e. given `-c` when starting solr) Otherwise you'll be running as a standalone server, which doesn't launch the embedded zookeeper. Can you connect to port 9983 if you use telnet or a zookeeper client? (for example the bundled `zkcli.sh` to upload/download configurations, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a better start with cloud mode :). I can connect now, but I don't see data. I'm searching in documentation, but if you have more advices, I will take it ;)

Comment: Ok, to conclude, as it is my first time with solr, I expected that DbVisualizer showed me list of tables, or something like this, when I clicked on the "table icon" for Solr connection. But instead, I only had an error "rror while executing SQL "SELECT * FROM "localhost:9983"."gettingstarted" limit 1000"... But, if I write SQL (for ex SELECT id, name FROM gettingstarted ORDER BY id) in SQL Commander tab, it is ok :)